# Wordpress Media can't load photo to insert on pages

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I was trying to insert an uploaded image on Wordpress site.

For some reason it won't just load the image and won't add my image.

Do you have any idea?

[image]

Comment: I faced similar problem. for me its my theme is the problem

Comment: so what should I do then to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false ); to the bottom of your wp-config.php file (just before the require_once line).

for reference see these links

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-add-media-to-pageproduct-with-wordpress-35

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/media-library-problem-cant-insert-images-into-pages-or-create-a-header

Comment: Might work however, I think this is a theme error or an error caused by a plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to deactivate your current theme and temporarily activate twenty eleven (or another standard wordpress theme) and test if it works now.

If it does, you'll have to check the theme files or contact the developer of the theme to fix it.

If it doesn't work, try to deactivate every plug-in one by one. So basically you check the file upload/insert function each time you deactivated one plug-in.

That's how you know if it's a theme/plug-in error or an error that wordpress causes.

Also update wordpress, all plug-ins and themes.

Let me know if you found out what causes it, we might be able to help you further.